# How can I mount a case insensitive ISO image on OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, mount, iso-image

I am trying to install a Windows program using [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) on OS X from an ISO but since the default filesystem on Windows is case insensitive and the ISO is mounted case sensitive, the installer is unable to find certain files.

How can I mount the ISO file case insensitive instead?

Comment: The iso must **be** case-sensitive to mount as that. macOS is also case-insensitive by default.

Comment: ah I see, I thought case sensitiviy might be a mount option - yeah the macos root filesystem is case-insensitive by default, but the filesystem I see when I mount the ISO is not